# Binary writing from Android-Java reading wrong from UE4-C++

Tags: java, android, c++, read-write, google-project-tango

I am writing a binary reader that needs to read in a very specific set of binary written by an Android Tablet. I have run into several issues reading this binary, the first and foremost being that it does not resemble the data I wrote in the first place. I have read a little bit about endianness, words, and how they are made on different systems and I am curious as to if this could be the root of the problem.
Any information would be good at this point, but the specific thing I would like to know is: Considering the lines below, why is the binary not being read in as the same value as it is written out as? How can I fix this?

Say numPoints = 5000.

(OUT FUNCTION - Android-java)
    `out.writeInt(numPoints);`
(IN FUNCTION - UE4-c++)
    `reader << numPoints;`

numPoints now equals some really really large number that I can't explain.

I am using Windows 8.1 x64 and a Google-Project-Tango Tablet.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading `numPoints`?  `operator<<` usually points the direction into stream...

Comment: You may also want to show more than just a line of code as to how you are writing out the data and reading in the data.

Comment: see if it works with `out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(numPoints));`

Comment: @immibis Your comment worked like a charm, the numbers match up on both ends. Just to be clear, this is because I was writing in little endian, and reading in big endian... or vice versa?

Comment: @JasonRyan -  writing big endian and then reading on little endian  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C++ code is probably reading numbers in little-endian. Java (at least DataOutputStream) writes binary numbers as big-endian.

It's probably simpler to fix this on the Java side since there's a built-in function for it:

```
out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(numPoints));
```

You should also check whether UE4 guarantees that binary files are little-endian, or whether it's the machine's native endianness - otherwise there's a chance that you might want to port your game to a big-endian platform and run into problems later.